# update new attribute into exists node firebase(realtime database)

Tags: javascript, firebase-realtime-database, react-native-firebase

I'm a newbie in firebase realtime database. i have got a data structures  as below. How can i update a new property (`TimeOut`) at the same node without loss current properties?

I would appreciate it if someone could help me this issue

[image]

Comment: Thanhs you for supported to me, but it's still does't work, maybe my syntax was wrong.

Answer (score 0):

If you only have to add the property to the node that you're showing that'd be:

```
firebase.database().ref('18-9/Working/TimeOut').set('5:20:30');
```

Or

```
firebase.database().ref('18-9/Working').update({ TimeOut: '5:20:30' });
```

Comment: i'm really sorry to make some bother, i just has created  the same new topic question (edit version) with firebase config and my code to update new property(TimeOut), could you please to check it and give me some advise ?  https://stackoverflow.com/q/73760345/20023345