# update new attribute into exists node firebase(realtime database) (edit)

Tags: javascript, firebase-realtime-database, react-native-firebase

I'm a newbie in firebase realtime database. i have got a data structures as below. How can i update a new property (TimeOut) at the same node without loss current properties?

[image]

has someone, he was supported me to update a new property with below method

```
firebase.database().ref('18-9/Working/TimeOut').set('5:20:30');
OR
firebase.database().ref('18-9/Working').update({ TimeOut: '5:20:30' });
```

, but it's still doesn't work, maybe my syntax was wrong.

I would appreciate it if someone could help me this issue

[image]

Comment: What error do you get? Can you share a screenshot of the same? And also you are missing the `import "firebase/compat/database"`. Firestore adn RTDB are different databases.

Comment: thank u so much for helping me to slove an issue, just with edit 
from "firebase/compat/firestore" to "firebase/compat/database",  the issue that i've got is done

Comment: Glad to hear that. I posted the same an answer below so others will know it's resolved.

Answer (score 1):

Firebase Realtime Database and Cloud Firestore are different databases. In this case, you are using RTDB but importing the Firestore SDK. Adding the Realtime DB SDK should resolve the issue:

```
import "firebase/compat/database"
```